# When some data is updated on the server how to live-updating user interfaces?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a website which is developed using laravel. I have two pages, First page is for submitting user details and second page is for listing data. For submitting user details, route or url is like www.test.dev/usersubmit For listing user details, route or url is like www.test.dev/userlist My purpose is when I push or submit user details from first page, In listing page (second page) data load without refresh page. For this purpose which technology need to study? Do we need node js or socket js? If there is any package available for laravel. Please help me to find a good solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use node/socket for push notification or you could use [pusher](http://pusher.com) service for the same result, and in the front end update the view when you receive a notification event.

also laravel 5.3 has built in support for pusher. see https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/broadcasting

alternatively you could use polling to check for updates every 30 seconds or so